# Problems with Views Load More module loading via AJAX

Tags: views

I tried to add the [Views Load More module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_load_more) to my semantic view but it doesn't load all of the view fields (e.g. image, etc.) when I use it with ajax. Can someone give me a hint why?

Here you can see the view:

http://www.mustxhave.com/testing

The site runs Drupal 7.43 and Views Load More v1.5. The view output is standard, no .tpl theming for this view.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the image path not the load more module.

I inspected the image in your view and found that it is being requested from this URL:
http://www.mustxhave.com/**mustxhave**/sites/all/themes/simpnews/images/xyz-300x500.jpg
which is wrong.

Removing **musthave** from the URL will fix the image path.
http://www.mustxhave.com/sites/all/themes/simpnews/images/xyz-300x500.jpg

This may be caused by one of these:

- Check the view settings for the image field.
- Check settings.php file for base_url variable value.
- Check if have Rewrite Base in the .htaccess file.

Comment: thanks but this was not the issue. Please have a look at the view output. Now i have made it so far, that the image is shown with ajax too but the field"social buttons" from the addthis module still not showing. Please click on "show more" then you will see that the loaded content is not the same then the usally shown content. But i dont understand why this field is not shown with ajax + load more

Answer (score 0):

I think issue in your case is of jQuery, as you are getting the error of `jQuery is not Defined`. Please see my attached screenshot.

Try to remove jQuery `(jQuery)` from addThis js file, there is also one extra semicolon in end of file.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried to delete the hole addthis.js but the toolbar buttons are not appearing either. Maybe you can explain me exactly what i have to change in this file?